# Jquery Ajax returns Undefined on accessing specific column

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

**ASP.NET CODE**
If there is any simpler way to convert Datatable to array or i can send datatable as Json in a simple way please do help me . but currently i have used the explicit method for this . may be i am doing something wrong correct me thanks

```
[WebMethod]
public static Sales[] getAll()
{
    DB db = new DB();
    DataTable dt = (db.select("SELECT * FROM DailySale"));
    List<Sales> sales = new List<Sales>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        Sales s = new Sales();
        s.Id=dr[0].ToString();
        s.Sale=dr[1].ToString();
        s.Date=dr[2].ToString();
        sales.Add(s);
    }
    return sales.ToArray();
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/getAll",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d[0]);
    },                        
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);

    }
});
```

** CONSOLE RESULT ON alert(data.d[0])**

Object {__type: "ProjectPackages.Sales", Id: "8", Sale: "9000", Date: "09/07/2015 00:00:00"}

The Problem i am facing is when i try to read the specific field(column) e.g id , sale or date it shows undefined .code i am using is . alert(data.d[0].id);
Please help me out in parsing this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert(data.d[0].Id);` - javascript is a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Is there a way to change the binary data to image ?